# Is there a way for com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper to process JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, java, json, jackson-databind

We have an existing function that uses com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper and formats the following JSON as com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.

```
{
  "headerName": "Column1",
  "field": "COLUMN1",
}
```

All good and it is working as expected. Now, we want to introduce events handling. To do that, we need to add a property in the JSON that makes it no longer a JSON but a JavaScript Object. Example below.

```
{
  "headerName": "Column1",
  "field": "COLUMN1",
  "onCellDoubleClicked": (event) => {
     this.onCellDoubleClicked(this, event, "COLUMN1");
   }
}
```

It is now throwing the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('(' (code 40)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"
```

I checked if Chat GPT will be useful and I got the following message:
[image]

Is there an alternative to com.fasterxml.jackson so I can process this JavaScript Object?

Comment: ChatGPT is right: the second listing isn’t valid JSON. There are JavaScript interpreters that can be embedded in Java applications such as [Nashorn](https://openjdk.org/projects/nashorn/), but it feels like there’s some important context missing from the question. How do you need to process this? What would invoke the event handler?

Comment: @TimMooret we have a UI that has a textarea input where users can input the sample JSON. Since this is a free text area, we are doing validation that why we're parsing the JSON input. So basically, we're just validating if the JSON passed by the user is valid.

Comment: Valid JSON or valid JavaScript? JSON is a subset of JavaScript syntax, and the second example is not valid JSON.

Comment: @TimMoore you are right, JavaScript for that matter.

Comment: If its JavaScript, then you would do `eval`, but with all the warnings that go with using `eval` on user input. Do you really want to give them the possibility to inject malicious code?

Comment: @trincot you are right. Allowing users to provide functions is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had another thought about this. It is a **bad idea** to allow users to input functions because it will lead to security vulnerabilities.

I ended up having flags instead.

```
{
  "headerName": "Column1",
  "field": "COLUMN1",
  "openPopup": "true"
}
```

Depending on the flag passed, pre-defined functions will get triggered.